# The problem of connecting SQLite to Python and Flask

Tags: python

When I connect sql to Python and run it using Flask and launch it in the browser, it only displays the last table, please help me

[Image for sql python](https://i.stack.imgur.com/R0bkz.jpg)
Code python in image

Comment: Please edit your question so that it contains [no image](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-should-i-not-upload-images-of-code-data-errors)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

expected `tab` in line 20 that all dictionaries save in the list.